# Creating a Single React Bundle That Can be Embedded in Remotely

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a composite UI (aka Micro Frontends).
I'm creating a micro app in React that is wrapped in an HTML Web Component that will be embedded in a larger legacy container app (currently written in ASP.NET MVC)

To do that, I have to generate a single `bundle.js` of my React micro app that I will embed by calling it via `<script ...`.

The problem is that whenever I build my app, it generates multiple bundles

[image]

And as far as I understand, the amount of chunks can change according to the size of the app.

I couldn't find a simple way to tell React to only generate a single bundle file that can be easily imported remotely.

What are my options?

Comment: This is done by WebPack and you can change it via your webpack configuration. It is slightly more complicated if you are using CRA as this is obfuscated.

Comment: @JacobSmit I don't think I have webpack. I created the app using Visual Studio. do you have a good guide that explains how to setup webpack?

Comment: What package are you using to handle building your React application and how are you connecting it with your MVC app?

Comment: I'm using `react-scripts` to build the app. I'll be connecting it to my MVC app by creating a custom web component that wraps the UI component https://medium.com/@gilfink/wrapping-react-components-inside-custom-elements-97431d1155bd

Comment: react-scripts is CRA (Create React App) it uses webpack to build out your app with a configuration that is best for the "Majority" which is awesome, until you aren't the majority. So if you NEED a single javascript bundle with no hash in the name you will need to update the webpack configuration to output it.